# How to measure and get the result in a Graph state

Tags: cryptography, graph-states

[image]

According to this definition, suppose I have a graph on $3$ vertices, $v_1,v_2,v_3$, such that I have the Graph state vector $$|G\rangle= |0++\rangle+|1++\rangle$$ Suppose I have a secret say $S=1$,so the encrypted graph becomes $$ZZZ|G\rangle$$, I see that I have $B=\{1,2,3\}$ as a c-accessible set since I have $D=\{1\}$ such that $|D|=1$, and $Odd(D)=\{2,3\}\subseteq \{1,2,3\}$. So for reconstruction players $2,3$ apply an S gate and player $1$ applies a $H$ gate so the state becomes $$|+\rangle\{(|0\rangle+i|1\rangle)(|0\rangle+i|1\rangle)\}+ |-\rangle\{(|0\rangle-i|1\rangle)(|0\rangle-i|1\rangle)\}$$
Now how do I proceed with the measurement, what does it say about measurement. For instance if Player 1 measures $|0\rangle$ on the first qubit, I am left with $$(|0\rangle+i|1\rangle)(|0\rangle+i|1\rangle)+(|0\rangle-i|1\rangle)(|0\rangle-i|1\rangle)$$, after that if Player 2 measures again $|0>$, then the third player is left with only the $|0>$ state on his qubit and say he measures it. So a total of $s_i=0+0+0$ and since $G_D$= empty graph, I get the reconstructed secret as $0$ which is not correct. Please can somebody tell how to measure, and what exactly is to be done.

Comment: The encrypted graph state $ZZZ|G\rangle = |0++\rangle - |1--\rangle$, I think. Then, after the $H$ and $S$ gates, you get the state that you describe with a $-1$ phase between the two terms. The measurement then works out differently.

Comment: Specifically, if you measure the first qubit to be $|0\rangle$, you get the state $i|01\rangle + i|10\rangle$. Measuring the second qubit to be $|0\rangle$ as well, the third qubit is then in the state $|1\rangle$.

Comment: Okay I will try this, but what do they mean in the proof. It seems complicated. The things that I understand about the graph state is for every X gate that you apply to a vertex there has to be some correction by the its neighbours and that correction comes in the form of a Z  gate. But how to write this coherently can you please explain. And even the comment yiu gave is a partial answer i will very appreciatively accept this. Atleast you gave me somr idea.